# Fetch order status label in custom module configuration

Tags: magento2, order-status

Magento 2:

I need to fetch all **order status labels list** (Ex. Processing, Pending, Complete...) in my custom module configuration settings.

I have searched a lot but they give result of sales orders label. But I need all order status labels.

Please take a look on screen shot. I want this red box order status labels. So admin can select multiple order status for further task.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code to get all the Order State and Status code.

```
$manager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$obj = $manager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\Collection'); 
print_r($obj->toOptionArray());
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek . But in which file I have to write this code ? I need to call it in configuration setting in my custom module. Would you please give more information ?

Comment: Let me know if you have still any question regarding this. Also, give useful vote to my answer by hitting UP arrow.

Comment: I need 15 reputation for up vote your answer... Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I made a piece of code :

```
/**
 * @var Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\Collection
 */
private $statusCollection;

/**
 * @var array|null
 */
private $status = null;

/**
 * Constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\Collection $statusCollection
 */
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\Collection $statusCollection,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->statusCollection = $statusCollection;
}


/**
 * @return array
 */
function getAllStatus() {
    if ($this->status === null) {
        $this->status = [];
        foreach ($this->statusCollection->toOptionArray() as $status) {
            $this->status[$status['value']] = $status['label'];
        }
    }
    return $this->status;
}

/**
 * @param $statusCode
 * @return string
 */
function getStatusLabel($statusCode) {
    $status = $this->getAllStatus();
    if (isset($status[$statusCode])) {
        return $status[$statusCode];
    }
    return $statusCode;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have a simpler working solution:

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Adminhtml\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\CollectionFactory;

class Model implements ArrayInterface
{
    protected $statusCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param CollectionFactory $statusCollectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CollectionFactory $statusCollectionFactory)
    {
        $this->statusCollectionFactory = $statusCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->statusCollectionFactory->create()->toOptionArray();
    }
}
```